# Using a context manager to choose db or file handler

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager

I want to be able to use a context manager to open either a `FileHandler` or `DBHandler` depending on argument. The 2 classes are context managers themselves. I could come up with the code below and was wondering if there's a better way to do this (please ignore any missing functions)?

```
class FileHandler:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._file = open(name, 'w+')
    def write(self, val):
        self._file.write(val)
    def close(self):
        self._file.close()
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        return False

class DBHandler:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._db = some_db_api.open(name)
    def write(self, val):
        # val is some query
        self._db.execute(val)
    def close(self):
        self._db.commit()
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        return False
        
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def get_resource(resource_type, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        if resource_type == 'file':
            resource = FileHandler(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            resource = DBHandler(*args, **kwargs)
        yield resource
        resource.close()
    except:
        resource.rollback()


if output_mode == 'f':
    with get_resource('file', name) as resource:
        for i in range(5):
            resource.write(str(i))
else:
    with get_resource('db', name) as resource:
        for i in range(5):
            resource.write(str(i))
```

Comment: Why do you have all these indirections in the first place? ``get_resource`` seems to serve no purpose *at all*, other than calling the undefined ``resource.rollback``. Instead of ``get_resource('file', name)``, why not use ``FileHandler(name)`` directly?

Comment: Personally, I would use an abstract class here to define an interface for the method names. You also define the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods in the base classes, meaning they should already be able to act as content managers. Either go fully with `get_resource` as the context manager and remove `__enter__`/`__exit__`, or remove `get_resource` and place the appropriate exit logic inside the `__exit__` handler.

Comment: Yes I agree, get_resource was an unnecessary indirection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `with` statement does not require a callable that *is* a context manager type – any expression that *evaluates to* a context manager works. This allows function calls, conditional expressions, as well as direct name references to provide the context manager.

You can remove practically all indirections, and directly select the appropriate context manager:

```
class DBHandler:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._db = some_db_api.open(name)
    def write(self, val):
        self._db.execute(val)
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        # make a commit of no error occurred, rollback otherwise
        if exc[0] is None:
            self._db.commit()
        else:
            self._db.rollback()

context = open(name) if output_mode == 'f' else DBHandler(name)
with context as resource:
    for i in range(5):
        resource.write(str(i))
```

In principle, the `... if ... else ...` could be inlined into the `with` statement as well. It is left separate for readability.

Comment: I think a factory method is still valid especially if the number of `Handler` classes grow. I would also raise an error if the string parameter doesn't match any valid resource.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was missing this crucial piece of information: "The with statement does not require a callable that is a context manager type"